# Charts using ggplot() to apply geom_text() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, geom-text

In learning of charts plotting in R, I am using the Australian AIDS Survival Data.

To show the genders in survival, I plot 2 charts with these codes:

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/MASS/Aids2.csv")


ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(sex, fill = as.factor(status)), position = "fill")  +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(as.factor(status), fill = sex))
```

Here are the charts.

[image]

Now I want to add the values (numbers and percentages) into the bars body.

geom_text () will do. I googled some references and tried different combinations for the geom_text (x, y, label) like xxx. They are not shown properly.

Wrong code:

```
geom_text(aes(as.factor(status), y = sex, label = sex))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems its lacking a `)` in your "wrong code"...

Comment: @Dalton, thank you. it still doesn't give me the wanted when ")" added. :)

Comment: Try with `geom_text(mapping=aes(x=as.factor(status), y=sex))` or just `geom_text(aes(x=as.factor(status), y=sex))`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it easiest to summarise the `data` outside of `ggplot` and then it became relatively simple.

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(sex, status) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100)

ggplot(data2, aes(sex, percent, group = status)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = status)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(percent,1)), position = position_stack(vjust = 
  0.5))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data2, aes(status, n, group = sex)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = sex)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]